# Need to evaluate a mathematical expression using a For loop

Tags: python, loops, eval, calculator

I have this code already for a calculator that takes string input:

```
keepAsking = True
equationList = []

while keepAsking:  # keep looping until keepAsking is false
    print("Please enter the mathematical expression you want the program to evaluate: \n")  # taking user input
    userInput = input()
    equationList.append(userInput)
    print("Do you have other operations to add? \n")  # another user input (choice)
    userChoice = input()
    if userChoice.lower() == "yes":  # if the user wants to keep asking
        keepAsking = True
    else:
        print(100*"-")
        print("|{0:<15s}|{1:^40s}|{2:>40s}|".format("Operation no.", "operation expression", "operation output"))
        # if not print the following
        print(100*"-")
        # For each equation get index and the item itself
        for i, item in enumerate(equationList):
            # evaluate executes python code
            print("|{0:<15d}|{1:^40s}|{2:>40.2f}|".format(i + 1, item, eval(item)))
        keepAsking = False
        print(100*"-")
```

but I want to replace the eval() function with For loops to evaluate the expressions and yield the same result, would that be possible?

Comment: I don't see how this program is even going to work as it is. Like if someone says `1*2` as their first input and then `yes` then `*3` it will result in an error, so perhaps instead of saying operations to add you might say mathematical expression again... and if you want to parse the string yourself to evaluate it of course that is possible. https://nerdparadise.com/programming/parsemathexpr

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
def calc(expr): return sum([sub([mul([div(x) 
    for x in x]) 
    for x in x]) 
    for x in parse(expr)])
# -- calc--         This function will flatten each list
#                   into a number in correct mathematical order.


def parse(expr, syms=['+','-','*','/']): return [
    parse(x, syms[1:]) for x in expr.split(syms[0])
] if syms else float(expr)
# -- parse --       This function will transform the input string
#                   into a nested tree of numbers (in the 4th branch.)


def div(xs): return div(xs[:-1])/xs[-1] if len(xs) > 1 else xs[0]
def mul(xs): return mul(xs[1:])*xs[0] if xs else 1
def sub(xs): return xs[0]-sum(xs[1:])
# -- div/mul/sub -- These functions will do calculation on
#                   lists in each eg [1,2,3] will be handled like 1-2-3 = -4


if __name__ == '__main__': print(calc("100+1/2*2-1+3"))
# -- test           This test will calculate the string 100+1/2*2-1+3
#                   and the output will be 103.0
```